# Combine result return by query into one string - sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, concatenation

Following query returns two rows.  I'd like to combine these two rows.  Is this possible?  This logic will later become one of the columns for another query:

```
select SUM(case 
        when FreeRentMonth = 'Y'
            then 1
        else 0
        end) as months
from LARBICRMFact
where rlm_spaceID in (
    select RefCRMSpaceID
    from #OneAE_Multiple_CRM_deals fs
    where fs.RefLeaseAssumptionID = '58500-TSPECTENB-LSPECTENB-0210'
    )
group by rlm_spaceID
```

Desired result:
**6|7**  (instead of 6 and 7 being in two separate rows).

NOTE*: The subquery can return 1 or many values.

Comment: Not my answer, but check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the values of `rlm_spaceID` to convert then rows into columns.

for e.g. say the values 6 and 7 are for rlm_spaceID "value1" and "value2".

```
rlm_spaceID   months
value1        6
value2        7
```

Something like this:

```
select SUM(case 
            when rlm_spaceID = 'value1'
                and FreeRentMonth = 'Y'
                then 1
            else 0
            end) as val1,
    SUM(case 
            when rlm_spaceID = 'value2'
                and FreeRentMonth = 'Y'
                then 1
            else 0
            end) as val2
from LARBICRMFact
where rlm_spaceID in (
        select RefCRMSpaceID
        from #OneAE_Multiple_CRM_deals fs
        where fs.RefLeaseAssumptionID = '58500-TSPECTENB-LSPECTENB-0210'
        );
```

Comment: The problem is it is random how many rlm_spaceIDs are returned by the sub-query.  It could be 1 or up to 10.  Is there a function I could create which would do this for me?

Comment: do you want to get the result in one row and one column? or one row and separate columns? the first one can be easily achieved.

Comment: Correct, I'd like the result in one row and one column.  However, I'll be passing the RefLeaseAssumptionID at row level from another select statement.  This could will pretty much become a column on that select statement.